# How to update a pool and shift-left in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program for a game. It is between the user and a virtual player. The game starts with a pool of consecutive integers 1-100. The size of the pool is based on a random generated number at the beginning of the game. At the start, both players' scores are 0. For each turn, the player picks one number from the pool. That value is added to the player's score, the computer gets the sum of all the remaining numbers in the pool that divide evenly into the player's pick. The player's pick and its divisors are then removed from the pool.

The player should be able to play the game as many times as she wants without ending the program. Instructions should appear on the screen only once at the start of the program.

For each turn, both players' current score, the current pool of numbers, and a prompt for a number to be entered should show onscreen. I have written the code until I get to the function that updates the pool of numbers after a turn - this is where I need help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class SlickPick {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);            
        int     []pool = new int[100];
        int     []divisors = new int[100];
        String  agreement;
        int     size;
        int     pick;
        int     numDivisors;

        // Program Heading
    printProgramHeading();

        // Instructions
    printInstructions();

        // User Agreement
    System.out.print("Would you like to play Slick Pick? (yes or no): ");
    agreement = read.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    if(agreement.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Program Ended");
    }else{

        // Pool Initialization
    size = createPool(pool);

        // User Input
    printPool(pool, size);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
    pick=read.nextInt();

        // Pool & Pick Validity
    while(!(pickValidity(pool, size, pick) && poolValidity(pool, pick))){
        System.out.println("Pick is invalid.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
        pick=read.nextInt();
    }

        // Data Processing
    numDivisors = getDivisors(pool, divisors, pick);

        // Output Section
    printDivisors(divisors, numDivisors, pick);
    System.out.println();
    printScores(divisors, size, pick);
    System.out.println();

       // Update pool
    poolUpdate(pool, divisors, size, pick);      

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Program Ended");  

   }
} // end main

// Function and Method Specifications
// Name         : printProgramHeading
// Description  : This method prints the program heading to the monitor in all caps and with a dividing line
//              : followed by a blank line.
// Parameters   : None.
// Return       : None.
public static void printProgramHeading(){
    System.out.println("\t\t\tGET DIVISORS");
    System.out.println("\t\t  ************************");
    System.out.println();
} // end printHeading


// Name         : printInstructions
// Description  : This method prints the instructions to the monitor  with a dividing line followed by
//              : a blank line.
// Parameters   : None.
// Return       : None.
public static void printInstructions(){
    System.out.println("\t\t\tINSTRUCTIONS");
    System.out.println("\t\t  ************************");
    System.out.println("At the start of the game, both the player's and Slick's scores are set to zero.");
    System.out.println("For each turn, the player picks one number from the pool. That value is added to");
    System.out.println("the player's score. Slick gets the sum of all the remaining numbers in the pool that");
    System.out.println("divide evenly into the player's pick. The player's pick and it's divisors are then");
    System.out.println("removed from the pool.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("For each turn, Slick must be able to get at least one number. If the player does");
    System.out.println("not have any picks left, the game is over and Slick gets the sum of all remaining");
    System.out.println("numbers in the pool. The highest score wins!");
    System.out.println();
} // end printInstructions


//Name          : createPool
//Description   : This funtion generates an array of consecutive integers from 1 to a randomly generated
//              : number no greater than 100.
//Parameters    : An integer array.
//Return        : An integer (the randomly generated number), representing the size of the array.
public static int createPool(int[]pool) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int size;
    int index;

    size=random.nextInt(100)+1;
    for(index=0; index < size; index++){
        pool[index] = (index+1);
    }
    return(size);
} // end createPool


//Name          : printPool
//Description   : This method prints the pool of numbers to the monitor no more than 10 per line.
//Parameters    : The pool array, and the size of the pool in that order.
//Return        : None.
public static void printPool(int[] pool, int size) { 
    int index;
    int count=0;

    System.out.println("The Pool:");
    for(index=0; index < size; index++){
        System.out.print(pool[index] + " ");
        count++;
        if(count == 10){
            System.out.println();
            count=0;
        }
    }
} // end printPool


//Name          : poolValidity
//Description   : This funtion determines if the current pool is valid.
//Parameters    : The pool array and the user's pick.
//Return        : True/false indicator.
public static boolean poolValidity(int[] pool, int pick){
    int poolIndex=0;
    boolean isValid=false;

    while(pool[poolIndex] < pick && !isValid){
        if(!(pick % pool[poolIndex] == 0)){
            isValid = true; 
        }else{
            isValid = false;
        } 
        poolIndex++;
    }
    return(isValid);
} // end poolValidity 


//Name          : pickValidity
//Description   : This funtion determines if the player's pick is valid.
//Parameters    : The pool array, the size, and the user's pick.
//Return        : True/false indicator.    
public static boolean pickValidity(int[] pool, int size, int pick){
    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid;
    int poolIndex=0;
    boolean found=false;
    boolean isValid=false;

    while(low<=high && !found){
        mid=(low + high) / 2;
        if(pick == pool[mid]){
            found = true;
        }else if(pick < pool[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
        }else{
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        while(pool[poolIndex] < pick && !isValid){
        if(pick % pool[poolIndex] == 0){
            isValid = true; 
        }else{
            isValid = false;
        } 
        poolIndex++;
        }
    }
    return(isValid);
} // end pickValidity


//Name          : getDivisors
//Description   : This funtion stores all the divisors of the user's pick into the divisor array.
//Parameters    : The pool array, the divisor array, and the user's pick, in that order.
//Return        : The number of divisors found.
public static int getDivisors(int[] pool, int[] divisors, int pick){
    int numDivisors=0;
    int index=1;

    while(index < pick){
        if(pick % index == 0){ 
            divisors[numDivisors] = index;
            numDivisors++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return(numDivisors);
} // end getDivisors


//Name          : printDivisors
//Description   : This method prints the contents of the divisors array to the monitor all on one line with
//              : a leading label.
//Parameters    : The divisor array, an integer representing the number of divisors, and the user's pick
//              : in that order.
//Return        : None.
public static void printDivisors(int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
    int index;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The divisors of " + pick + ": "); 
    for(index=0; index < size; index++){
        System.out.print(divisors[index] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
} // end printDivisors


//Name          : printScores
//Description   : This method prints the player's and Slick's scores to the monitor all on one line with
//              : a leading label.
//Parameters    : The divisor array, an integer representing the number of divisors, and the user's pick
//              : in that order.
//Return        : None.
public static void printScores(int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
    int playerScore = 0;
    int slickScore = 0;
    int index=0;

    playerScore = playerScore + pick;
    for(index=0; index < size; index++){
    slickScore = slickScore + divisors[index];
    }

    System.out.print("\tPlayer's Score: " + playerScore);
    System.out.print("\t\tSlick's Score: " + slickScore);
} // end printScores
```

Below, I used the binary search to find the indexes of the divisors array and then used those indexes as the start values. At this point of the program, it has gone through one turn of the game - now the pool needs to be updated so that it does not contain the number that the player picked or the divisors of that number, and the second turn can start. How do I do that?

```
//Name          : poolUpdate
//Description   : This function modifies the contents of the pool as a result of a turn of play.
//Parameters    : The pool array, the divisors array, the size, and the user's pick.
//              : 
//Return        : 
public static void poolUpdate(int[] pool, int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid;
    boolean found=false;
    int start=0;
    int index=1;

    while(low<=high && !found){
        mid=(low + high) / 2;
        if(divisors[index] == pool[mid]){
            found = true;
            start=divisors[index];
        }else if(divisors[index] < pool[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
        }else{
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        for(index=start; index < size-1; index++){
            pool[index]=pool[index+1];
        }
    }
} // end poolUpdate


//Name          : printFinalScores
//Description   : This method prints the player's and Slick's final scores and the winner to the monitor 
//              : with leading labels.
//Parameters    : The divisor array, an integer representing the number of divisors, and the user's pick
//              : in that order.
//Return        : None.
```

}

Comment: Omg omg this is JAVA! Not C. In Java you document your functions using JavaDoc!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you desire that no number is picked twice right? In this case you can create a `List<Integer>` and proof - before each turn - whether the number picked is in the `List<Integer>`.
To do that, you can just write the following:

```
//define somewhere a ArrayList
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void poolUpdate(int[] pool, int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
    if (!intList.contains(pick)){
        int low=0;
        int high=size-1;
        int mid;
        boolean found=false;
        int start=0;
        int index=1;

        while(low<=high && !found){
            mid=(low + high) / 2;
            if(divisors[index] == pool[mid]){
                found = true;
                start=divisors[index];
            }else if(divisors[index] < pool[mid]){
                high = mid-1;
            }else{
                low = mid+1;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            for(index=start; index < size-1; index++){
                pool[index]=pool[index+1];
            }
        }
    }
    //add the value to the list to assure that it is not used twice.
    intList.add(pick);
    } // end poolUpdate
```

You can do the same thing with other numbers.

Hope this helps.